# Delete entry from Exchange calendar when delegate denies meeting request

Tags: calendar, exchange-2013, delegation, mailbox

I created a Room-Mailbox in Exchange.
This Mailbox will be used to manage vacation Days.
I delegated control to a user to deny and accept vacation requests.
The requestee is informed correctly about approval or dismissal of his request.
But if the request is dismissed the calendar entry for the request is not deleted from the Room-Mailboxes Calendar.

Here is the output of Get-Calendarprocessing for the Mailbox

RunspaceId                          : bad4c927-c410-4832-bde8-8cb40eab6315
 AutomateProcessing            : AutoAccept 
  AllowConflicts                      : True
   BookingWindowInDays                 : 180
   MaximumDurationInMinutes            : 1440
   AllowRecurringMeetings              : True
   EnforceSchedulingHorizon            : False
   ScheduleOnlyDuringWorkHours         : False
   ConflictPercentageAllowed           : 0
   MaximumConflictInstances : 0
   ForwardRequestsToDelegates          : True
   DeleteAttachments                   : True
   DeleteComments        : True
   RemovePrivateProperty               : True
   DeleteSubject                       : True
   AddOrganizerToSubject : True
   DeleteNonCalendarItems              : True
   TentativePendingApproval            : False
   EnableResponseDetails               : True
   OrganizerInfo         : True
   ResourceDelegates                   : {SharePtest.local/ITOU/IT Boss}
   RequestOutOfPolicy               : {}
   AllRequestOutOfPolicy               : False
   BookInPolicy                        : {}
   AllBookInPolicy         : False
   RequestInPolicy                     : {}
   AllRequestInPolicy                  : True
   AddAdditionalResponse : True
   AdditionalResponse                  : Urlaubsanfrage wurde übermittelt. Bestätigung erfolgt seperat
  RemoveOldMeetingMessages            : True
   AddNewRequestsTentatively           : False
   ProcessExternalMeetingMessages      : False
   RemoveForwardedMeetingNotifications : False
   MailboxOwnerId       : SharePtest.local/Users/Holidays IT
   Identity                    : SharePtest.local/Users/Holidays IT
   IsValid                     : True
   ObjectState                         : Changed

Does anyone know how to get the mailbox to delete dismissed appointments ?

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss an appointment in outlook essentially this cancels the reminder and would NEVER delete the appointment from a calendar.  To delete the appointment from the calendar if the appointment is pending it would have to be rejected or manually deleted.